# Save matrices of a loop to reuse them

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have a loop which creates me 11 special `oxo` matrices.

```
for i=1:1:11
    %create the special matrices called D_i
    D_i
end
```

And now I am trying to save this matrices to reuse them in another program

```
A = cat(1,NaN(o),D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4,D_5,D_6,D_7,D_8,D_9,D_10,NaN(o),D_11,NaN(o),NaN(o))
```

How can I do that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can't you use `A = cat(1,A,D_i)`, defining `A` as an empty matrix before loop?

Comment: I recieve the error that D_i is undefined. Could you explain it a little bit more please?

Comment: Edit your question and put the codes for D_i, and what is the deal with `NaN`? where do you use them? It seems random.

Comment: Don't you just want (inside the loop) `D(i) = ...` or else `D(i,:) = ...` or `D(i,:,:) = ...` etc